# Nginx and Watermarking

Tags: nginx, watermark

I use [ngx_http_image_filter_module](http://sysoev.ru/nginx/docs/http/ngx_http_image_filter_module.html) module for serving images in my project.
Everything works perfectly. And now I want to dynamically put watermarks on images.

I can't put them on upload because image sizes are often being changed.
So, is that possible with nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this patch](https://web.archive.org/web/20140703035012/http://blog.zakovinko.com/2010/08/watermark-nginx.html). I found it through internet.

It is allow to nginx to apply watermark's. This implementation only works with using function, which change size of image.